# Unary and binary minus operators for calculator in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am working on a calculator project. The user can enter several numbers with different operators and I calculate the sum of the line.

**Example (> = user input)**

```
> -2 + 4 - 5 + 6
3
> 9 +++ 10 -- 8
27
> 3 --- 5
-2
```

The program must calculate expressions like these: 4 + 6 - 8, 2 - 3 - 4, and so on. It must support both unary and binary minus operators. If the user has entered several same operators following each other, the program still should work.

Considering that the even number of minuses gives a plus, and the odd number of minuses gives a minus! Like this: 2 -- 2 equals 2 - (-2) equals 2 + 2

My plan was to create a list, count the number of '-' in each string, and if the number of '-' % 2 == 0 replace all '-' with 1 '+' else with '-'. Here is how far I have gotten, but I can not quite figure out the way to do it, since I do not understand the reduce() function if that is even the right function for my purpose.

```
fun readInput(): List<Int> {
    val input = readLine()!!.split(" ")
    input.forEach {
        if(it.count{it == '-'} % 2 == 0) it.reduce { acc, c -> acc }
    }
    return
}
```

I want to return a list so I can use it in my sum function later

```
    fun summa(input: List<Int>) {
        println(input.sumBy { it })
    }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm, http://reedbeta.com/blog/the-shunting-yard-algorithm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you were trying to do with `reduce` but `String.reduce { acc, c -> acc }` has equivalent behavior to `String.first().toString()`, except that it iterates the String for no reason.

Breaking this problem down, I think you want to split the input into chunks that end in integers. Then convert these chunks into integers that are either positive or negative.

I struggled to come up with a Regex that could split the String appropriately, so this scans it for integer boundaries and splits it that way.

Once you have these chunks, you can scan for negative signs and use that to multiply the integer by 1 or -1

```
fun readInput(): List<Int> {
    val input = readLine()!!
    val splits = mutableListOf(0)
    for (i in 1 until input.length){
        if (input[i - 1].isDigit() && !input[i].isDigit())
            splits.add(i)
    }
    splits.add(input.length)
    val chunks = splits.zipWithNext().map { input.substring(it.first, it.second) }
    return chunks.map { piece ->
        val multiplier = if (piece.count { it == '-' } % 2 == 0) 1 else -1
        (piece.filter { it.isDigit() }.toIntOrNull() ?: 0) * multiplier
    }
}
```

By the way, you don't need `.sumBy { it }`. You can just use `.sum()`.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. This helped me solve my problem. Out of personal interest, in your opinion is there a better approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: This was the simplest I came up with for the very specific problem you described. But a more complicated strategy would be needed if you need to add support for other operators. Also, my above code would silently process the input normally even if there are syntax errors like numbers with no operator between them or decimal places and other symbols and letters.